# RX and buffering

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm trying to obtain the following observable (with a buffer capacity of 10 ticks):

```
Time    0    5    10   15   20   25   30   35   40
        |----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
Source  A  B C   D        E F  G    H

Result            A                 E         H
                  B                 F
                  C                 G
                  D

Phase   |<------->|-------|<------->|<------->|
             B        I        B         B
```

That is, the behavior is very similar to the Buffer observable with the difference that the buffering phase is not in precise time slot, but starts at the first symbol pushed in the idle phase. I mean, in the example above the buffering phases start with the 'A', 'E', and 'H' symbols.

Is there a way to compose the observable or do I have to implement it from scratch?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
IObservable<T> source = ...;
IScheduler scheduler = ...;
IObservable<IList<T>> query = source
    .Publish(obs => obs
        .Buffer(() => obs.Take(1).IgnoreElements()
            .Concat(Observable.Return(default(T)).Delay(duration, scheduler))
            .Amb(obs.IgnoreElements())));
```

The buffer closing selector is called once at the start and then once whenever a buffer closes. The selector says "The buffer being started *now* should be closed `duration` after the first element of this buffer, or when the source completes, whichever occurs first."

Edit: Based on your comments, if you want to make multiple subscriptions to `query` share a single subscription to `source`, you can do that by appending `.Publish().RefCount()` to the query.

```cs
IObservable<IList<T>> query = source
    .Publish(obs => obs
        .Buffer(() => obs.Take(1).IgnoreElements()
            .Concat(Observable.Return(default(T)).Delay(duration, scheduler))
            .Amb(obs.IgnoreElements())));
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();
```

Comment: I'm not very skilled with RX and I have to admit that I don't really fully understand your solution, but it seems do the job. But I have to point an... issue?

Comment: Sorry, I press the enter key.
[cont.]
`'Publish'` should multicasts source elements to many subscribers, but, from my tests, it seems that subscribing `'query'` multiple times it regenerates new elements for each subscriber.
I'm not really sure it is an issue, but I don't know how to define it!

Comment: @Atropo The version of `Publish` I used only multicasts the `IObservable<T> obs` in its lambda expression. See how I use `obs` three times in the `Publish` lambda expression? Even though I do that, subscribing to `query` once will in turn subscribe to `source` once. If you want to multicast a single subscription to `query` you can do it like I show in the edit.

Comment: I spent most of the day to study that version of `Publish` (the one with the selector), but I don't completely understand it! :-P There's not much documentation for that overload. Anyway I accept the solution.